# Find distribution $\mathcal{D}$ such that, if $A, B\overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal{D}$, then $A+B$ and $AB$ have the same distribution

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

We need to find all distributions $\mathcal{D}$ such that, if we sample twice from it and take the sum, we will result in the same distribution as if we have sampled twice and taken the product. Or in math notation, if $A,B \overset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}\mathcal{D}$, then $A+B$ has the same distribution as $AB$.

I am currently able to identify these distributions:

- Dirac $\delta$ distribution at $0$;
- Dirac $\delta$ distribution at $2$;
- If $K$ is a discrete uniform random variable on $\\{0,1,\dots,m-1\\}$ where $m$ is an odd number, then the distribution for $2 \cos{\frac{2\pi k}{m}}$ satisfies the property above;

  - this is because $(2\cos{(a+b)})(2\cos{(a-b)})=2\cos{2a}+2\cos{2b}$. When $a$ and $b$ each iterates through $T=\\{0,\frac{1}{m}2\pi,\dots,\frac{m-1}{m}2\pi\\}$, the pairs $(a+b,a-b)$ and $(2a, 2b)$ also iterates through $T^2$, modulo $2\pi$.
- The limit case of $m\to\infty$: if $\theta$ is a uniform random variable on $(0, 2\pi)$, then the distribution of $2\cos\theta$ (i.e. $2\times{}$ the x-coordinate of a uniform random point on the unit circle).

*Source:* This is a just-for-fun question that randomly pops into our heads when I was chatting with my friends. I am not sure if we can exhaustively classify all distributions satisfying the property.

Following are my basic thoughts.

Intuitively, $\mathcal{D}$ should not have too long of a tail, because otherwise the product would grow faster than the sum. If we assume that all of its moments exist, and let $a_n = \operatorname{E}[A^n]$, then:

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{E}[{(AB)}^n] &= \operatorname{E}[{(A+B)}^n] \\\\
\operatorname{E}[{A}^n]\operatorname{E}[{B}^n] &= \operatorname{E}[\sum_{0\leq k\leq n} {n\choose k} A^k B^{n-k}] \\\\
a_n^2 &= \sum_{0\leq k\leq n} {n\choose k} a_k a_{n-k}\\\\
a_n^2 - 2a_n &= \sum_{0<k<n} {n\choose k} a_k a_{n-k}
\end{aligned}$$

With an initial condition $a_0=1$, this defines a recurrence relation on the moments. However, the quadratic equations have two solutions for each $n$, and we end up with an infinite binary tree of $\\{a_n\\}$ sequences. **This means that there may be many solutions.** Realistically, a lot of the branches end up with imaginary solutions.

I wrote a Mathematica one-liner to filter out only the positive integer solutions:

```
With[{nn = 15}, 
 Map[Table[a[i], {i, 0, Evaluate[nn]}] /. # &, 
  Solve[Join[Table[a[n] >= 0, {n, 0, nn}], 
    Table[a[n]^2 == Sum[Binomial[n, i] a[i] a[n - i], {i, 0, n}], {n, 
      0, nn}], {a[0] == 1}], Integers]]]
```

With a bit of OEIS, I found out that some of the solutions are the number of closed walks (round trips) of length $n$ on a cycle graph (e.g. [A054877](https://oeis.org/A054877)), which correspond to the real-parts-of-roots-of-unity distributions above.

Comment: Just want to say it seems a very interesting problem!